How to Uninstall SANS SIFT Workstation from Ubuntu?
I need some help with uninstalling the SANS SIFT workstation from my Ubuntu PC. I installed it using the following commands:
sudo dpkg -i cast-v0.14.47-linux-amd64.deb
sudo cast install teamdfir/sift

Now, I'm not sure how to remove it properly. If anyone knows the correct steps to uninstall SIFT, I'd really appreciate the guidance. Thanks in advance!

You can remove sift with cast, and then optionally remove cast as well.
sudo cast remove teamdfir/sift

sudo apt remove cast

